# фигуры pygame'а и pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pillow

Как можно создать изображения в форматах .jpg, .png и др. Чтобы 2д фигуры pygame'а тоже были отображены в этом фото. Мне не нужен скриншот, мне нужно полноценное фото, чтобы каждый пиксель был виден на нём.
Можете предлагать любые модули или библиотеки которые могут это.

Это скриншот рабочей области моей программы, на нём  при детальном просмотре видно, что некоторые пиксели размылись.

[image]

И если пользователь создаст картинку разрешением больше чем его экран монитора или экрана смартфона, то некоторые пиксели не отобразятся в конечном файле и из - за этого пользователю будет неприятно пользоваться моей программой, посколь указанное разрешение "потерялось".

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC

Comment: Приложите что ли картинку - что вы хотите видеть. Вроде и понятно, а вроде и не совсем

Comment: Zhihar, извенте я просто когда - то улышал формулеровку, что pygame рисует не фигуры, а приметивы.